# Using VLOOKUP to search different sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to search if a number exists in one of the 32 sheets I have in my workbook.
I have tried to use the below mentioned code but it's not working because VLOOKUP is not deciphering the variable(n). Kindly help:

```
Private Sub SearchAll_Click()
Dim SearchCriteria As Double, s As Integer
SearchCriteria = Me.SearchBox.Value
s = 0
For s = 0 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
s = s + 1
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SearchCriteria, Sheets(s).Range("A:A").Value, 1, False) = SearchCriteria Then
MsgBox ("The Number " & SearchCriteria & " is available in list " & Sheets(s).Name)
Exit For
Else
MsgBox ("The Number is Unavailable")
End If
Next s
End Sub
```

Legend:

- SearchAll is a button used to initiate the search.
- SearchCriteria is a textbox used to input the value you want to search for.

Comment: @simoco : how can i get the sheet name instead of the sheet codename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems in the way you use `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` to determine if a specific value exists in your workbook. I have modified your code to the following:

```
Private Sub SearchAll_Click()
    Dim SearchCriteria As Double, s As Integer
    Dim Lookup As Variant
    Dim Match As Boolean

    SearchCriteria = Me.SearchBox.Value

    For s = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        Lookup = Application.VLookup(SearchCriteria, Sheets(s).Range("A:A"), 1, False)
        If Not IsError(Lookup) Then
            MsgBox ("The Number " & SearchCriteria & " is available in list " & Sheets(s).Name)
            Match = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next s

    If Match = False Then MsgBox ("The Number is Unavailable")
End Sub
```

Here I have, instead, made use of `Application.VLookup` which will return an error to the variant variable `Lookup` if the search value were not found in the specific sheet. Then, by looking at the error state of `Lookup` it can be determined if the search value were found. Also, I have moved the message `The Number is Unavailable` outside the loop in order to avoid it being triggered each time the value were not found in a specific sheet.